# Amazon RDS with MariaDB Cost

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Open source ( e.g. MariaDb ) databases are preferred as opposed to proprietary databases ( SQL Server, Oracle ) because they don't have any licensing cost. It is cheaper for companies and clients.

Does the same thing apply on RDS Services for Amazon and other Cloud services? Are db services for open source databases much cheaper than those of proprietary databases? If cheaper, by how much percentage?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using Open Source databases reduces the cost of database services.

Pricing for Amazon Relational Database Service can be found at: [Amazon RDS Pricing - Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/)